# Fixing fail2ban regex rule for php-url-fopen filter

Tags: regex, fail2ban, fopen

I'm fixing default [php-url-fopen](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/blob/master/config/filter.d/php-url-fopen.conf) filter to allow some GET query parameters which I'm using in my system (it's not publicly available, but I would still like to block unnecessary requests). The problem is that I got working regex for one name of parameter, but I can't get working regex for two parameters where second opiton is combined from two names. I'm using fail2ban 0.8.11 - here is working (fail)regex:

```
^<HOST> -.*"(GET|POST).*\?.*(?<!outer)\=http\:\/\/.* HTTP\/.*$
```

And here is the regex which doesn't work:

```
^<HOST> -.*"(GET|POST).*\?.*(?<!outer|type\=outer\&url)\=http\:\/\/.* HTTP\/.*$
```

When I try to start fail2ban service with non-working regex, I get this message:

```
ERROR  NOK: ('Unable to compile regular expression \'^(?:::f{4,6}:)?(?P<host>[\\w\\-.^_]*\\w) -.*"(GET|POST).*\\?.*(?<!outer|type\\=outer\\&url)\\=http\\:\\/\\/.* HTTP\\/.*$\'',)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my second regex is:

```
^<HOST> -.*"(GET|POST).*\?.*(?<!outer)(?<!type\=outer\&url)\=http\:\/\/.* HTTP\/.*$
```

Both words/parameters in GET query must be separated and contained only in one negative lookbehind.